# Avoiding quotations after import "List" or "Data"

Tags: import

I observed that when exporting a List, no matter if I put "List" or "cvs" the result is always the same: after importing, the data appears with quotations:

```
   cont1 = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
   cont2 = {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}};
   tosave = {cont1, cont2};

   Export["ContTest.lst", tosave, "List"];
   Export["ContTest.csv", tosave, "csv"];
   asDat = Import["ContTest.lst", "List"]
   asCsv = Import["ContTest.csv", "csv"]
```

Out[540]= {"{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}", "{{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}"}

Out[541]= {{"{2, 3}", "{3, 4}", "{5, 6}"}, {"{7, 8}", "{9, 10}", 
  "{11, 12}"}}

The solution I found is to export in ".cvs" format and transform with ToExpression:

```
     merd = ToExpression@Import["ContTest.csv", "csv"]
```

Out[520]= {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}}

How to avoid the quotations when using "List"? Or better, why the list is imported with quotations?

Comment: It is not clear to my what the question is. Please rephrase it and illustrate it with an example. If something doesn't show, *show what you did*.

Comment: For example, one can only guess at what you might mean by *no matter if I put "List","Data" or whatever*.

Comment: I do not see why you need ToExpression here. Even without that, things are okay. To keep things simple, you might want to export in `.m' format.

Comment: I already have a large amount of data exported in "List" format... that´s why I would like to import and recover it in the original format ("List")

Comment: @JuanManuelGomba If the format is indeed `"List"` as you claim, why do you import as `"CSV"`? Also, it would help to see the problematic data, since, as @HimalaySenapati already pointed out, the example provided works as expected

Comment: You exported the list twice into the same CSV: `{cont, cont}`, so it imports the whole list back twice into two columns. However CSV doesn't allow nesting beyond 2 dimensions, so they're imported as text. If you do `Export["ContTest.csv", cont, "csv"]`, it should work.

Comment: It looks that I have to reformulate the question. It is just an example, that is why i wrote {cont,cont} twice. I will modify the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cont = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

Put[cont, cont, "data"]

merd = ReadList["data"]
```

> {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}}

or if the brackets are included

```
Put[{cont, cont}, "data"]

merd = Last@ReadList["data"]
```

> {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}}

```
merd == {cont, cont}
```

> True

Comment: Thanks Chris, but it does not have the same format as {cont,cont}

Comment: @JuanManuelGomba You mean you need the brackets included?  Added edit.

Comment: Great, thanks. Now I see that if I directly write

       ReadList["ContTest.lst]

the list is correctly read.

Answer (score 1):

From Chris Degnen post I find that just doing

```
  ReadList["ContTest.lst"]
```

the data is obtained without quotations.